# How can I change appearance of Blogger comment-box?

Tags: templates, layout, blogger, appearance

Good day !

I have  [this blog](https://farmersandfriends.blogspot.com/).

I would like to have these changes (for comment-box):

- rounded corners (inside too)
- same colour for background but for boxes with text I want to be set on white with black borders

An example of my blog is [this](https://farmersandfriends.blogspot.com/p/contact_22.html) or the image below.

[image: that]

I saw & tried more tutorials of the internet but no solution for me.

Do you can help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you add the code for the page with CSS then someone can help you out. We help, not code for you

Comment: I don't know how to upload my code here. I will try. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5rqbwyr03ep9yp5/theme-2032450883604899397.xml?dl=0)

Comment: Paste it as seperate pieces of code. and if its too big then add it as jsfiddle

Comment: upload your code in jsfiddle.net or codepen.io in HTML box and CSS box

Comment: @ Syfer @ Rooter Boy I have just uploaded my template file on Dropbox, see link above.